# Is there a simple way to disable a specific modal for small screens?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using the modals in Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1 and my modals are quite useless and borderline intrusive for screens narrower than 700 pixels.

Is there a simple feature or method to disable modals for small screens?

EDIT: Added relevant html:

```
<div class="post-body-img">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
        <img src="test.jpg">
    </a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <a data-dismiss="modal">
                    <img src="test.jpg">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use Bootstrap responsive utilities classes.  You could add `visible-md` and `visible-lg` to the modal link.  The link that launches the modal will display only on medium (>=992px) or large (>= 1200px) screens.

[More info at Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

If you don't want to hide the modal link on smaller screens, then just add another one.  So you'll have two links like this:

```
<div class="post-body-img">
    <a class="hidden-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> <!--hidden on mobile, add hidden-sm to hide on tablet-->
        <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    </a>
    <a class="visible-xs"> <!--shows on mobile, add visible-sm to show on tablet-->
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100">
    </a>
</div>
```

[Bootply demo](http://www.bootply.com/74T0bFGMR6)

Comment: Unfortunately, this still turns on the dark layer (`modal-backdrop`), and becomes impossible to remove because there are no close buttons, etc.

Anyway to easily prevent the backdrop for showing for small screens?

Comment: Sorry, you said modal link. But I need the modal link. I am using the modals to "zoom" into images, sort of a lightbox effect. So, I can't exactly hide the thumbnails. I want to prevent the modals from showing up without removing the buttons or images that `data-toggle` it.

Comment: Ok, I can take a stab at figuring that out but you need to add the relevant html to your question.

Comment: Done so. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to hide a modal and its backdrop using CSS with an `!important` declaration, which overrides the inline `display:block` style on the modal elements when the modal is open. To hide it at a certain size just put the following CSS inside the relevant media query:

```
#yourModalID.modal.in,
#yourModalID.modal.in + .modal-backdrop.in
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but isn't working. Not sure I'm doing something wrong. My code:    .options_section_modal.modal.in{display:none !important;}
.options_section_modal.modal-backdrop.in{display:none !important;}