# Hide modal popup for smaller screen like andriod and ios phone

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to hide modal popup for smaller screen like on android and ios phones and allow to  visible only for web browsers.

i tried bootstrap css class "d-none d-lg-block" but it doesn't work

```
<div class="modal fade d-none d-lg-block" id="PageAlertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PageAlertModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">I tried this also but its not working, here is full div
   <div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block">
       <div class="modal fade" id="PageAlertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PageAlertModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
               <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                       <h5 class="modal-title" id="PageAlertModalTitle" runat="server"></h5>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body" runat="server" id="PageAlertModalBody"></div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox mr-5">
                           <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="HidePageAlertCb" />
                           <label class="custom-control-label" for="HidePageAlertCb">Don't show this again</label>
                       </div>
                       <button type="button" id="PageAlertCloseBtn" class="btn btn-secondary">Close</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: found this old topic, could help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221163/is-there-a-simple-way-to-disable-a-specific-modal-for-small-screens

Comment: @noris45 - i your took reference from your link and tried this "modal fade hidden-xs" But its not working

Answer (score 1):

you can use these classes to make it work

```
<div class="d-none d-sm-none d-md-none d-lg-block">
   <div class="modal fade" id="PageAlertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="PageAlertModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        content here
    </div>
</div>
```

I have made a working sandbox example as well

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-leftpad-q4gdt?file=/index.html:340-409&resolutionWidth=1024&resolutionHeight=765

Comment: Let me try and come back to you

Comment: this code is hiding the modal but master page cannt able to accessible ,even cannt able to click as well...feels like modal is there invisible mode so cannt able to click on main page....

Comment: it must be because of the modal and fade classes, I have modified my answer, please check like this.

Comment: Perhaps you are coorect,Let me try this Naveen.

Comment: Even though i removed the fade property but still hidden popup where main page looking faded , you cannt click on that

Comment: i just check your test code ,Its working for text but if u create a simple modal popup then problem occurs, it fade the main page

Comment: Interestingly, bootstrap modal implementation and classes are different than previous versions, any ways, I have made the code work here

https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-leftpad-q4gdt?file=/index.html

Comment: I test your code separately , its working perfectly and hiding for mobile simulator screen , But i dont in my solution when i use same css class for modal-fade , it dont show the modal but disabled parent screen , so i cannt even click the parent screen :(

Comment: Looks like some other class or styles are getting over written, please inspect every element and see any CSS is getting overwritten.

Comment: i am checking other css as well which called in page

Comment: I edited my question and included my whole div, where i used ur css class as well , before the my div start.